# Merge [visualstyles] and [visual-styles]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

After briefly looking at these two non-self-descriptive tags ([visualstyles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visualstyles) and [visual-styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-styles)) they both seem to be about Microsoft Windows [visual styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773187(v=vs.85).aspx) from Vista and later, i.e. their UI themes. Should these tags be merged?

Comment: I created a synonym, you can [vote for it](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visualstyles/synonyms).